# Retrieving Session data in a Spring MVC application

Tags: spring-mvc

I have inherited a Spring MVC application.  I'm familiar with .NET MVC, and I think I'd have designed this thing very differently, but working with what I have, here's what I'd like to do:

Current Design:

SearchController - for submitting and rendering search result.  Each individual search result has an Add/Edit/Delete option which submits a request to a different contoller.

> ```
> @RequestMapping(valur={"/searchResult.do"}...)        
> public ModelAndView searchResult(@ModelAttribute GlobalPojo pojo) {
>   //here I'd like to store the pojo in session so that the search results
>     //can be re-rendered after an Add/Edit/Delete action
> }
> ```

CrudController

> ```
> @RequestMapping(value = { "/modifyAction.do" }, method = { org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.GET }) 
> public ModelAndView modifyRecord(@RequestParam("id") String uid) {
>     //here I'd like to return to the results page after completing an action 
> }
> ```

This GlobalPojo is used as a parameter and result all over the place, so I can't very well make it a session-scoped bean.  I think what I can do is:

1. Add this to the SearchController:  @SessionAttributes("searchPojo")
2. Modify the @ModelAttribute --> @ModelAttribute("searchPojo")

However, what I'm not sure how to do is then access the searchPojo from the CrudController, as I would like to set a message property on it for display on the search results page.

The examples I see of passing session to controller actions do not use attributes, so I'm just not sure what that should look like.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you're using a version of Spring greater than 3.1.2.RELEASE this should just be a case of adding `@SessionAttributes("searchPojo")` to the top of your `CrudController` and then specifying the `ModelAttibute("searchPojo")` as a parameter on the `modifyRecord` method.

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("searchPojo")
public class CrudController {
    ...

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/modifyAction.do" }, method = { org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.GET }) 
    public ModelAndView modifyRecord(@RequestParam("id") String uid, @ModelAttribute("searchPojo") SearchPojo pojo) {
        //here I'd like to return to the results page after completing an action 
    }
}
```

Spring should then look for the `searchPojo` in the session and pass it through to the `modifyRecord` method. You should then be able to set a message property on the `searchPojo` inside `modifyRecord`.

There's an example of sharing data between controllers using `SessionAttributes` here: [Spring 3.0 set and get session attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227395/spring-3-0-set-and-get-session-attribute)

Comment: Thanks - we unfortunately are on 3.0.5 or something like that.  But if that doesn't work,I'll try the version listed in your link.

Comment: The @SessionAttribute approach did not work (again, we're in an earlier release), but the link provided did work. Namely, passing HttpSession to the controller actions involved and doing session.setAttribute in the search action and session.getAttribute in the CRUD controller actions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try getting the session from request and set pojo as a session attribute.

Comment: right, but then it becomes a question of accessing the Request object

Comment: Have you tried put it as an argument? Like `public ModelAndView searchResult(@ModelAttribute GlobalPojo pojo, HttpServletRequest req){HttpSession session = req.getSession();}`

Comment: "The examples I see of passing session to controller actions do not use attributes, so I'm just not sure what that should look like." - So no, I wasn't sure if I could just do that, or if it needed to be in some specific order, as the examples seemed to suggest.