# in spring3 mvc how to display single value in different jsp pages

Tags: spring-mvc

```
    Welcome.jsp page
    <a href="addStudent">Click here for registration form</a>

    student.jsp is the registration page

    <s:form method="post" action="addStudent" commandName="student">

    <s:label path="name">NAME:</s:label>
    <s:input path="name"/><br>
    <font color="red"><s:errors path="name"></s:errors></font><br>

    result.jsp

    <table>
    <tr>
    <td><font color="red">NAME:</font></td>
    <td><font color="blue">${student.name}</font></td>
    </tr></table>

    studentmoredetails.jsp

    <s:form method="POST" action="studentadditionaldetails" commandName="studentMoreDetails">
    <s:label path="fullname">FULLNAME:</s:label>
    <s:input path="fullname"/>

    final result.jsp

    <table>
    <tr>
    <td><font color="red">NAME:</font></td>
    <td><font color="blue">${name}</font></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><font color="red">FULLNAME:</font></td>
    <td><font color="blue">${studentMoreDetails.fullname}</font></td>
    </tr></table>

    I am having 2 controller class and two bean class

    RegistrationController.java

    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("addStudent")
    public class RegistrationController {
        Student studentobj=new Student();
        @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public String toRegform(ModelMap model)
        {                   
            model.addAttribute("student", studentobj);      
            return "student";
        }

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String addStudent(@Valid Student login, BindingResult result,ModelMap model) 
        {           
            if (result.hasErrors()) {
                return "student";
            }

            login = (Student) model.get("student");
            if ((login.getName()==null))
            {
                return "student";
            }
        //  model.put("student", login);        
            return "result";        
        }       

    Student.java (bean class)
    private int age;
        @NotEmpty
        @Size(min=3,max=15)
        private String name;    
    // getters and setters

    AdditionaldetailsController.java
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("studentadditionaldetails")
    public class AdditionalDetailsConroller {
        @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public String additionalForl(ModelMap model1)
        {       
            StudentMoreDetails additional=new StudentMoreDetails();
            model1.addAttribute("studentMoreDetails", additional);
            return "studentmoredetails";
        }
        @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)  
        public String additionalDetails(@Valid StudentMoreDetails login,BindingResult result,ModelMap model1)
        {       
            if (result.hasErrors()) 
            {
                return "studentmoredetails";
            }
            login=(StudentMoreDetails) model1.get("studentMoreDetails");        
            if (login.getFullname()==null)
            {
                return "studentmoredetails";
            }
            else
            {
                return "finalresult";
            }
        }
    }
     StudentMoreDetails.java(bean class)
    private String fullname;
    //getters and setters

    web.xml file 

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springdispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>

      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springdispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>

    springdispatcher-servlet.xml file is
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.pratap.javashades.controllers"></context:component-scan>

    <bean id="viewResolver"

            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/JSP/"></property>

            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource"

            class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">

            <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/messages" />

    </bean>     

    </beans>

    i am displaying both name and fullname values in the finalresult.jsp, but only fullname value i am getting, name value is empty in finalresult.jsp. please help me how can i display both the values in finalresult.jsp page. Please tell me how to achieve sesion for above??
```

i am displaying both name and fullname values in the finalresult.jsp, but only fullname value i am getting, name value is empty in finalresult.jsp. please help me how can i display both the values in finalresult.jsp page. Please tell me how to achieve sesion for above??
        Thanks in advance
    Hope somebody will guide me soon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `finalResult.jsp` is looking for an attribute called `name`, but there is no attribute called `name` available in the request at that point.

If you want to pass the name that was captured by the first controller `RegistrationController` to the second controller `AdditionalDetailsController` then it may be easiest just to use the session for this.

**RegistrationController**

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addStudent(HttpSession session, @Valid Student login, BindingResult result,ModelMap model) 
    {           
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "student";
        }

        login = (Student) model.get("student");
        if ((login.getName()==null))
        {
            return "student";
        }

        session.setAttribute("student", login); // Set the Student in session

    //  model.put("student", login);        
        return "result";        
    }
```

Then in `finalResult.jsp` you should be able to access the `Student` directly from the session:

**finalResult.jsp**

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><font color="red">NAME:</font></td>
<td><font color="blue">${sessionScope.student.name}</font></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><font color="red">FULLNAME:</font></td>
<td><font color="blue">${studentMoreDetails.fullname}</font></td>
</tr></table>
```

As a side note - you should not store the `Student` in an instance field in `RegistrationController` due to the multi-threaded nature of controllers. This should be created locally within the method.

```
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String toRegform(ModelMap model)
    {                   
        model.addAttribute("student", new Student()); // Create student
        return "student";
    }
```

Comment: The OP should probably use a single model but I like this solution for addressing the immediate problem

Comment: thank you very much Will Keeling, I have waited almost 15 days to know about this. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

```
add these lines to your controller class

@SessionAttributes({"student"})
public class RegistrationController {
.
.
.
}

@SessionAttributes({"student"})
public class AdditionalDetailsConroller {

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)  
    public String additionalDetails(@Valid StudentMoreDetails login,BindingResult result,ModelMap model1,@ModelAttribute Student student)
    {   
        System.out.println("stu"+student.getName());
        if (result.hasErrors()) 
        {
            return "studentmoredetails";
        }
        login=(StudentMoreDetails) model1.get("studentMoreDetails");        
        if (login.getFullname()==null)
        {
            return "studentmoredetails";
        }
        else
        {
            return "finalresult";
        }
    }   
}

finalresult.jsp will be
<table>
<tr>
<td><font color="red">NAME:</font></td>
<td><font color="blue">${student.name}</font></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><font color="red">FULLNAME:</font></td>
<td><font color="blue">${studentMoreDetails.fullname}</font></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227395/spring-3-0-set-and-get-session-attribute